# How to compare(less than or equal to) two sql columns in C# from code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck at comparing a combobox value with a SQL Column. I am trying to do it from VS 2010 with C#. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Please find below, my SQL table.

```
Rings  NR     Name  Dia
=======================
10     12     a     15  
10     24     b     18  
10     15     c     21  
10     9      d     24  
10     7      e     15  
10     19     f     18  
10     33     g     24  
10     36     h     13
```

What I am trying to compare values of `Rings` column and `NR` column.

My SQL query is this.

```
select * from tblData  where Dia=15 and (Rings<=NR)
```

I am able to run this query successfully in SQL and get the desired results but I am stuck to achieve this in C#. How can I compare two columns in C#?

My C# code is:

```
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuoteProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
 {
     {
         try
         {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmbbx.SelectedItem.Text);
            command.CommandText = "Update tblData set Rings= " + 
                                     cmbbxRings.SelectedItem.Text+" ";
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            command.CommandText = "(select * from tblData where Dia=" + 15 +
                                     " and NR="+(a)<="NR"")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
         }
         catch (SqlException ex)
         {
         }
```

I am struggling to write this part of the query in C#:

```
 (NR="+(a)<="NR)
```

Comment: warning ** your code might be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: In the SQL query you gave you are comparing Rings to NR but then in your `CommandText` you are comparing NR to NR with that syntax error in between. Can you clarify what is the target SQL query?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for bringing it to my notice. I will add the input validation before it hits the query.

Comment: Hi Von, Ahh!! I think, I just need to compare rings with NR (a<=NR) as I have written in the query. And I am unsure of how to compare Rings to NR in C#. My target SQL query is `select * from tblData  where Dia=15 and (Rings<=NR)`. Yes I agree that the syntax is wrong and I think, I am not able to get the right syntax because I am lacking an idea to compare two column values.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should user Parameters to avoid sql injection. Try doing the below changes, which should solve your problem and will use a better way of executing queries from C# avoiding the Sql injection.

replace this part of your code:

```
command.CommandText = "(select * from tblData where Dia="+15+" and NR="+(a)<="NR"")";
```

with this code:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from tblData where Dia=@Dia and NR<=@NR";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dia", 15));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NR", a));
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. Will parameterize it.

Answer (score 0):

To try the obvious.
If the query works in SQL then why not use it?

```
command.CommandText = "select * from tblData  where Dia=15 and Rings<=NR";
```